# identifying a calculated column and reading value from it

Tags: sql, hive

I have a simple table containing data of a batch of students and 
their score for different years (the data may not be realistic, but it's 
just an example).

```
Name    Dept       HOD         Year1     Year2    Year3    Year4
Sam     Science    Christie    76.23     34.65    45.67    23.45
Mike    Science    Christie    57.987    26.98    43.98    78.34
Bonny   Maths      Christie    64.87     67.23    34.09    12.87
Ben     English    Simon       43.98     54.76    55.87    76.87
```

Now the requirement is, considering 2015 as point of reference, if the 
user enters 2018 and wants data for Sam in Science department under 
Christie's management, then the value from column Year3 (i.e.2018-2015) 
is expected for all those conditions.

```
For example - 
[case
when Name='Sam' and Dept='Science' and HOD='Christie' then Year*
when Name='Bonny' and Dept='Maths' and HOD='Christie' then Year*
when Name='Ben' and Dept='English' and HOD='Simon' then Year*
end]
```

I have already tried the sql -

```
select Value from (
select concat('Year', abs(2018-2015)) as Value from Class where 
Name='Sam' and Dept='Science' and HOD='Christie')
```

So, when I am hardocoding Year3 in the above query instead of the formula, 
it's working fine. When I separately firing computed Value, its is giving 
output.
    select concat('Year', abs(2018-2015) as Value from Class

But when I am integrating the two , my query is only giving Year3 as a 
string. Whereas I want to pick the value for that column.

May be I am doing something wrong, I am not sure, but any suggestion is 
welcome to solve this problem.

I came across a post advising use of coalesce() for dynamically calling a 
column. so i tried that too -

```
select coalesce(Value, T.period,0) as Value from (
select concat('Year',(abs(2018-2015)))as period, Name, Dept, HOD from 
Class where Name='Sam' and Dept='Science' and HOD='Christie') as T 
where T.Name='Sam' and T.Dept='Science' and T.HOD='Christie'
```

But I am receiving error -

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: 
line 1:16 Invalid table alias or column reference 'Value': (possible 
column names are: period, Name, Dept, HOD)
```

Comment: hi, regarding your last sql and your error about "Value". This is wrong: "..coalesce(Value, ..." who it's Value? it's a column name?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select (case when @year = 2016 then year1
             when @year = 2017 then year2
             when @year = 2018 then year3
             when @year = 2019 then year4
        end) as value
from class c
where hod = 'Christie'
```

Comment: No Gordon, 
When I give 2016 as input, I want something like this -

Sam     Mike
76.23   57.987

...

Comment: Hardcoding the column in the case statement seems like a solution in this example, but the actual table has close to 100 columns like this and hardcoding wouldn't solve this. Also, as per the requirement filter should be like Name='Sam' and Dept='Science' and HOD='Christie'